# Configuration xml for Content Porter Sdl Tridion 2011

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, content-porter-2009

I am trying to invoke content porter from command line. As an input parameter we need to provide a config xml to content porter. I am able to understand most of the pattern of config xml but i am not able to understand the pattern of values for ItemSubType and IsExported tags in import config xml. Can someone help me out in understanding the pattern of values for the above tags.

Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: Normally you create this XML from Content Porter itself, there's an option after you select which items to export to _save_ the current settings. Then you can use this XML file as the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to play with this manually? I'm not 100% sure, but I can point you in the right direction.

`ItemSubType` might be set for components (Xml or Multimedia), Schemas (schema type), or TemplateBuilding block (C#, Assembly, Compound, etc). I think it's mostly used to show if there's a binary content along with the item itself.

`IsExported` is what it says it is. As you know Content Porter is exporting each item together with the items it depend on. You can filter out some of the dependencies, if you know that you have these items on the target system. For filtered out items, `IsExported` is set to false. For example, you want to export a component. By default, you will have to export schema of this component, folder in which the schema reside, publication with its default items and whatever other dependenices there might be. But you are 100% sure that on your destination system you already have this publication with the folder you need and schema, so to save time you can decide to filter all of this out and export only component. In this case, schema, and everything else will still be added to dependency table, but IsExported will be set to false.